# Backbone Model change data in one instance affects another

Tags: backbone.js, pass-by-reference, javascript, backbone-model

I just had a weird bug when using Backbone.Model

so I have the model declaration something like:

```
var MyMode = Backbone.Model.extend({
   defaults:{
      'someList': []
   },

   initialize: function(){
      _.bindAll(this, 'toString', 'castFromString');
   },

   toString: function(){
      return this.get('hierarchyNameList').join('+');
   },

   castFromString: function(str){
      var strArray = [], index = 0;
      if (str) {
         strArray = str.split('+');
      }
      for (index = 0; index < strArray.length; index++){
         this.get('hierarchyNameList').push(strArray[index]);
      }
   }
});
```

then I tried to test it

```
(function () {
'use strict';

var assert = function(condition, message) {
    if (condition !== true) {
        throw message || "Assertion failed";
    }
};

var mA = new MyModel({'someList': ['a','b','c']});
var mB = new MyModel();
mB.castFromString('a+b+c');

//I have a added a equals function to array prototype and tested it
assert(mA.get('someList').equals(mB.get('someList')));     //true

var mC = new MyModel(mA.toJSON());    //behaves as expected
var mD = new MyModel();   //for some reason its list already contains the list from B
mD.castFromString(mB.toString());    //since castFromString used push, now B and D both has array of length 6

assert(mC.equals(mA));    //success
assert(mC.equals(mD));    //fail, mc has arrayLength 3, mD has 6


 }).call(this);
```

The actual code is more complicated than this, but I think this is where I am probably doing something wrong, any suggestion on why this would happen? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with your defaults

```
defaults:{
  'someList': []
},
```

objects in JavaScript are passed by reference not by value. It means that all instances, for which you didn't explicitly specified `someList` value will share array created in `defaults` definition above. To avoid it you can define your `defaults` as a function:

```
defaults: function () {
    return { 'someList': [] };
},
```

This will create new array for every instance of `MyModel`, so they won't share the same array.

Comment: Great Thanks! Didn't really know how the defaults work in Backbone Model

Comment: It's worth it to poke through the Backbone source code if you're uncertain about how it does something (although I'm not sure that would have helped for this question). It's incredibly well-documented and easy to understand.

https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js